# Android kills my Threads/AsyncTasks

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I run my asynctask class of activity, then finish the activity, and asynctask still works. Android after some time killing my asynctask. I tried to add to the function run `"Process.setThreadPriority (Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_FOREGROUND);"` or `"Process.setThreadPriority (Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);"` but asynctask is still killed.

Yes I know they are Services, but I want the task was completed after the work done, and do not work all the time in the background as Services.

Comment: AsyncTask is designed for brief background threads, not long-running operations. If you need something that outlives your Activity, create a Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `IntentService`. This is different from a regular Service. `IntentService` will result in the `service` closes it self when it is done. `IntentService` is not running on the UI thread so you don't need to "handle" it as you need to do with a service..
You start it, it does some work and when it finishes it closes itself, exactly what you need.

There is no way for you to insure that the `Asynctask` will finish, since it's not build for that purpose.

Also, a `service` is not "running" as in taking cpu when it has nothing to do even if it's open.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add that this task is to connect to the server socket and transfer of large data and network actions may be executed only on a different thread than the UI thread.

1. Is intentservice blocking the UI thread?
2. If I run intentservice, and then finish() activity, whether intentservice can be killed by the system.

Comment: No, I forgot about it. An intent service is not running on the UI thread (A regular service do run on the UI thread).
It is perfect for what you need. It is made exactly for things like that.

Comment: // this - activity
Intent service_intent = new Intent(this, App.FtpSendFileIntentService.class);
startService(service_intent);
finish();

service_intent is still killed by system when the system needs RAM.

Comment: Sure it is... There is super absolutely no way for you to do anything that would prevent the OS from stopping you. Nothing.
When you use a service (or IntentService) it gets the top most priority and will be killed last and long after all of your activities are killed. You can stop looking for a "magic" way, It does not exist.  
There is one way that you will not like... If you use a Service you can make it "sticky" and than it will restart if the os kills it and run your code again.